# AZURE b2C Signin Flow shows only Email signup

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Just created my first Azure AD B2C from scratch and tried to add a SignIn Flow.

I followed for that this [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-sign-up-and-sign-in-policy?pivots=b2c-user-flow) but the List of Identity Providers there just show **Email signin**.

In the List of "Configured Identity Providers" for All Identity Providers I can see

Active Directory

Microsoft Account

Email one-time passcode

How to add at least a AD Provider to a new Flow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the main B2C portal page, on the LHS you'll see "Identity providers". Click this.

There are a few pre-built, otherwise, click "Add custom OIDC provider" at the top left.

Once they are added, they will appear in the "Identity providers" tab in the user flow you are using.

Comment: actually it was laready there as an option of the local account. but helped me finding it and makes sense now . Thanks